# Is there a way to only show an iframe element when present in an object in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am trying to find a way to display only the `iframe` element of some HTML that is being delivered to my Angular app.

In my template, I can use a `*ngIf` to see if there is the tag present, but I am unaware of way to only show the iframe from the object, and not the rest of the HTML.

```
<div *ngIf="item.content.indexOf('iframe') > 0" class="item">
   <div (click)="this.navigateToPost(item.id)">
      <h2 [innerHTML]="item.title"></h2>
   </div>
   <div class="iframe-container"[innerHTML]="this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(item.content)">
   </div>
</div>
```

In my `<div class="iframe-container"[innerHTML]="this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(item.content)"></div>` I would like to find way to only show the iframe code in the `item.content`.

Does anyone happen know of a good approach to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You can give the iframe a class and then in your component logic apply `display: none` in case it needs to be hidden.

For example like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    (document.querySelector('.iframe-class') as HTMLElement).style.display = 'none'
}
```

Edit:

My bad seems like you're trying to only display the iframe and hide the rest of the content. In this case you could CSS pseudo-class ':not()'

First apply class:

```
<div [innerHTML]="html" ngClass=[{'my-class': condition}]></div>
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.my-class:not(.iframe-class) {
  display: none;
}
```

I haven't tested it, so let me know if that works.

Comment: I am actually looking to do the opposite. Show only the iframe and hide the rest of the html.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I will give it a shot and see how it works.